# What does 'async in a function declaration' do in a function without await?

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I have a function returning a Promise, without any awaits in body. What is the difference between those two snippets, if awaiting for them seems to work the same?

```
export async function getTags(
  tagTypeId: number
): Promise<Tags[]> {
  return getAllPages('/tags.json', {
    tagTypeId
  });
}
```

```
export function getTags(
  tagTypeId: number
): Promise<Tags[]> {
  return getAllPages('/tags.json', {
    tagTypeId
  });
}
```

Calling

`const tags = await getTags(tag.typeId);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question *What does 'async in a function declaration' do in a function without await?* the answer is *nothing*.

Well, almost *nothing*.

If your function returns a value, it gets wrapped in a `Promise` object:

```js
async function myFn() {
    return 1
}

function myFn2() {
    return 1
}

console.log(myFn()) // Promise, not 1
console.log(myFn2()) // 1
```

So in a nut shell adding `async` does two things:

- It allows you to use `await` inside the function
- It makes sure the function **always** returns a Promise object.

Also `async` functions will not throw Errors but instead return them as a rejected `Promise` object:

```js
async function fn() {
    throw new Error("My error")
}

console.log(fn()) // Promise (rejected)
```

Comment: Quick follow up - is it a good practice to still add 'async' just to emphasize that it's asynchronous?

Comment: @JakubJ I had a discussion about this exact point on this site. In my opinion, I wouldn't do it.

Comment: It also means if any errors are thrown within the function, they will cause the returned `Promise` to reject instead of bubbling up out of your function. So you may need to handle errors differently when using `async`. Using `await` kind of inverts this though, so it's often fairly intuitive when using them together

Comment: @MarkHanna That is a good point - thanks! Will add to the answer.